# Insert values into wordpress table only once

Tags: database, wordpress

I have written insert query in function.php
    $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO $religion_table (religion_val)VALUES('A'),('B')");

Now every time I refresh page these values getting added into table again and again.
I want to insert it only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make unique  field in data base.

Answer (score 2):

You can maintain in session if you have already inserted that value in database or not
if inserted set flag in session

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options here:

1. Make the field in the database unique.
2. Adjust the query to be `INSERT IGNORE INTO table`